# How to select Dev Express's WPF GridControl row?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I want to select GridControl's row, after data binding:

> 1. Get selected row
> 2. Bind GridControl with new Data
> 3. Select GridControl's row

I'm trying so, but with no success:

```
int selectedRowhandle = gridControl1.View.GetSelectedRowHandles()[0];

gridControl1.DataSource = "DataSource...";

gridControl1.View.SelectRow(selectedRowhandle);
```

How can I do this in DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.GridControl?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to get selected row after stting datasource?

Comment: No. I want to remember selected row and after binding, select it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only changed this:

```
gridControl1.View.SelectRow(selectedRowhandle);
```

to

```
gridControl1.View.FocusedRowHandle = selectedRowhandle;
```

and it works.

Comment: Please let me know the Event name to get the selected row?

Comment: You can use this code where you need it. For example GridControl's TableView has FocusedRowChanged event.

Comment: Sorry @Vano Maisuradze the code 'int selectedRowhandle = gridControl1.View.GetSelectedRowHandles()[0];' doesnt work in my Devexpress WPF application for Devexpress Grid..

private void TableView_FocusedRowChanged_1(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            int selectedRowhandle = grdCompany.View.GetSelectedRowHandles()[0];
                       
        }

Comment: What is you grid name? You must use your grid name instead of gridControl1

Comment: yes offcourse i have changed it. but it says 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataViewBase' does not contain a defination for GetSelectedRowHandles()[0];' do u have any idea?

Comment: Oh they removed this function. Please see: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B203067.aspx